# php download from server

Tags: php, file, session, download

I am trying to download files from server that I uploaded via html form.
If I try to download files that I had uploaded everything works good but if I try to download other people's files they are broken (0 kb size).
The download link is generated by a page for every user:

```
$_SESSION['u'] = $username;
echo '<a href="/download.php?file='.$entry.'">'.$entry.'</a>';
```

If I echo($_SESSION['u']) I have the right username referred to user which I want to get the files.

And download.php is:

```
session_start();
$u = $_SESSION['u'];

$file = basename($_GET['file']);
$percorso = '/home/fosco/documents/'.$u.'/'.$file;

if(!$file){ // file does not exist
    die('file not found');
} else {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($percorso).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($percorso));
    readfile($percorso);
    exit;
}
```

Where is the mistake?
I don't understand why I am able to download certain file and not other.

I also tried changing permissions to 777 but nothing changed.
Moveing files to public_html, if I go to the public url the files are not broken but anyway I am not able to download it trought download.php

If I download the broken file from ftp it is ok, not broken.
Thanks for the help.
Fosco

Comment: *"but if I try to download other people's files they are broken"* - Sounds like you're trying to use someone else's session.

Comment: If files for other people are store in other sessions, why would you think they are stored in your session?  the `$u` part.

Comment: *Hint:* Error reporting.

Comment: No sorry, I am using session to store username that I choose. If I want Mike's files I set $username = 'mike'

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the file you request does not actually exists.

Your if-statement only checks if the variable `$file` is not false/empty/zero.
For checking if a file exists use the function [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)